# Uploaded file just 7 byte in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel and i make an upload file function. The file is uploaded, but the file size is just 7 byte from 8MB

Here's my code:

```
if(Input::file('audio')){
  $file = Input::file('audio');
  $filename1  = $slug . '-' . time() . '.' . $file>getClientOriginalExtension();

  $path1 = Storage::disk('uploads')->put($filename1, 'uploads');

  $part->audio = $filename1;
}
```

Here's the result :

[file property result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwREE.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files),

> You need to provide the file contents to the second argument of
>   `put()` method,

**change**

```
  $path1 = Storage::disk('uploads')->put($filename1, 'uploads');
```

**To**

```
  $path1 = Storage::disk('uploads')->put($filename1, file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: it turn into a folder that contain .bin file now, but the file size is true

Comment: @AlfaritsiHamdani so a file size is right but extension is `.bin`?

Comment: yes, the .bin file named with random alphabet, but the folder named like the filename1 variable